# How to change this JavaFX into using a ControllerFactory

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have looked into using ControllerFactory a lot, to allow this code to be instantiated from a database, and have cross-controller compatibility. But with my original setup different from others I found online, I found it extremely hard to follow along, and use what would fit into my program from theirs. Any advice on where to start?

Current Controller creation -

```
        // get Main Class package name to get correct files path
        String pathRef = mainRef.getClass().getPackage().getName();
        // set FXRouter current route reference
        currentRoute = route;
        // create correct file path.  "/" doesn't affect any OS
        String scenePath = "/" + pathRef + "/" + route.scenePath;




        // Creates controller for route
        Controller_Factory cf = new Controller_Factory();
        Object controller  = cf.CreateController(route.scenePath);


        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(controller.getClass().getResource(scenePath));
        loader.setController(controller);


        Parent root = loader.load();



        // set window title from route settings or default setting
        window.setTitle(route.windowTitle);
        // set new route scene
        window.setScene(new Scene(root, route.sceneWidth, route.sceneHeight));
        // show the window
        window.show();


    }
```

Controller Example-

```
public class BuyController extends Controller {

    @FXML
    public Button CloseAppButton;
    @FXML public Button SwitchToProfileButton;
    @FXML public Button SwitchToSellButton;
    @FXML public Button SwitchToBuyButton;
    @FXML public Button SwitchToMainButton;

@FXML public TextField BuyText;


String AmountBought;

    public void initialize (URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        CloseAppButton.setPrefHeight(30);
        CloseAppButton.setPrefWidth(56);

        SwitchToBuyButton.setPrefHeight(30);
        SwitchToBuyButton.setPrefWidth(56);

        SwitchToMainButton.setPrefHeight(30);
        SwitchToMainButton.setPrefWidth(56);

        SwitchToSellButton.setPrefHeight(30);
        SwitchToSellButton.setPrefWidth(56);

        SwitchToProfileButton.setPrefHeight(30);
        SwitchToProfileButton.setPrefWidth(56);
    }
    public void OnBuyButton (ActionEvent event) {
AmountBought = BuyText.getText();
System.out.println("You have bought " + AmountBought + " of crypto");
BuyText.clear();
    }


    @Override
    public void initilize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }


}
```

Current Controller_Factory-

```
public class Controller_Factory {

    private static final Controller_Factory instance = new Controller_Factory();

public static Controller_Factory getInstance() {
    return instance;
}



public Object CreateController (String routeScenePath) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException {



    Object controller = null;



    switch (routeScenePath) {
        case  "Buy.fxml":
            controller = new BuyController();
            break;
        case "Error.fxml":
            controller = new ErrorController();
            break;
        case "Home.fxml":
            controller = new HomeController();
            break;
        case "Profile.fxml":
            controller = new ProfileController();
            break;
        case "Sell.fxml":
            controller = new SellController();
            break;
        default:

    }
   System.out.println(routeScenePath);
    return controller;
}


}
```

How would I pass this info with the said controller? (This is not real code I have, but an example of configuration JSON I want to pass with the controller.)

```
  "HomePage": {
    "ValidPages": [
      "BuyPage",
      "SellPage"
    ],
    "InternalID": "HP"
  },
  "BuyPage": {
    "ValidPages": [
      "HomePage"
    ],
    "InternalID": "BP",
    "Cryptos": [
      "BTC",
      "LTC"
    ]
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn’t do anything other than create a controller by calling the default constructor on a class specific to each FXML. This is exactly the default behavior. Why don’t you simply specify the controller class directly in each FXML file in the usual way, and avoid calling either `setController(…)` *or* `setControllerFactory(…)`?

Comment: @James_D That is a great question! I would like to be able to use JSON with controllers, so customizing a Controller_Factory would be the best way to do it.

Comment: It’s still not clear what you’re asking. Why do you need a controller factory to use JSON in your controllers?

Comment: Agh, Im sorry if I did not answer properly, I will try my best to give my reasons. 
What I am trying to accomplish-
configuration JSON is either iterated over or the specific controller entry is extracted via key, with each key having a list of arguments for an associated controller. Regardless of how many arguments there are, that entire section of the config is shoved into the factory.  Read in some simple configuration JSON that has at least one entry for every page (it could just be as simple as having the name of each page and a list of pages you can go to)

Comment: I will update my original post with my current work Progress. If this still was not clear, I apologize. I'm trying to explain it as I understand it, which is obviously not very well :)

Comment: A `controllerFactory` is just a function that takes a `Class` and returns an object. When the `FXMLLoader` loads the FXML, it passes the class defined in the `fx:controller` attribute to that function and uses the resulting object as the controller. The “default controller factory” simply invokes the no-arg constructor on the class to create the object. Nothing in your question, or comments (as far as I understand them) shows any need to do anything other than the default.

Comment: Updated question with more info at the bottom. Hopefully that clears up what I am trying to do.

Comment: Create a suitable Java representation of that (in a class). Make your controllers have a constructor that takes an instance of that class. Use reflection in the controller factory to invoke that constructor and return the result.

Comment: Would it be too much for me to ask you to give visual examples? If you put that in the Answer Question I can add it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller factory is simply a `Callback<Class<?>, Object>` whose `call(Class<?> type)` function takes the class defined in the `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML file and returns the object to be used as the controller. This is invoked by the `FXMLLoader` at the time the FXML is loaded.

I think your question is asking if you can use a controller factory to automatically populate controllers with data that's stored in JSON, which will be read at runtime.

You can do something like this:

```
public class NavigationInfo {

    private final Map<String, PageNavigationInfo> pageInfoPerPage ;

    public NavigationInfo(Map<String, PageNavigationInfo pageInfoPerPage) {
        this.pageInfoPerPage = pageInfoPerPage;
    }

    public PageNavigationInfo getInfoForPage(String page) {
        return pageInfoPerPage.get(page);
    }
}
```

```
public class PageNavigationInfo {

    private final String internalID ;

    private final List<String> validPages ;

    private final List<String> cryptos ;

    // .... etc
}
```

```
public class NavigationControllerFactory implements Callback<Class<?>, Object> {

    private final NavigationInfo navigationInfo ;

    public NavigationControllerFactory() {
        // read and parse JSON and create NavigationInfo instance
    }

    @Override
    public Object call(Class<?> type) {
        try {
            for (Constructor<?> c : type.getConstructors()) {
                if (c.getParameterCount() == 1 && c.getParameterTypes()[0].equals(NavigationInfo.class)) {
                    return c.newInstance(navigationInfo);
                }
            }
            // no suitable constructor, just use default constructor as fallabck
            return type.getConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Now just define the `fx:controller` attribute in each FXML in the usual way. E.g. for `Buy.fxml` do

```xml
<BorderPane ... fx:controller="com.yourcompany.yourproject.BuyController">

    <!-- ... -->
</BorderPane>
```

Then

```
public class BuyController {

    private final PageNavigationInfo navInfo ;

    public BuyController(NavigationInfo navigationInfo) {
        this.navInfo = navigationInfo.getInfoForPage("BuyPage");
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // do whatever you need with navInfo
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was not able to make it work for my situation, but I thank you.

Comment: @Phantom It would probably help if you described your "situation".